# How can I use PAD function (from PADR() package) for multiple data frames?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, padr

I have 24 files (1 for each hour of the day, HR_NBR = Hour Number) and I've to pad the dates in each of the files.

AS-IS data:

```
CLNDR_DT    HR_NBR  QTY
01/07/2016  1   6
03/07/2016  1   10
```

TO-BE data:

```
CLNDR_DT    HR_NBR  QTY
01/07/2016  1   6
02/07/2016  NA  NA
03/07/2016  1   10
```

I can use the pad function for each file, like this:

```
chil_bev1_1 = pad (chil_bev1_1, interval= "day") # Hour1
chil_bev1_2 = pad (chil_bev1_2, interval= "day") # Hour2
```

and so on.

And it works. But I want to use a loop or LAPPLY.

I tried several variations of these 2 codes, but none of them worked:

```
df1 = data.frame (chil_bev1_1)
df2 = data.frame (chil_bev1_2)
dflist = c("df1","df2")
```

## CODE1:

```
x = function(df) {df %>% pad}
allpad = lapply(dflist,x)
```

## CODE2:

```
x = function(df) {pad (df)}

allpad = lapply(dflist,x)
```

The error is

> "x must be a data frame".

I'm new to R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: look at this example on how to make a list of dataframes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames

Comment: Thank you, @SatZ. I solved it using the COMPLETE package from TIDYR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Here's the answer:

```
hour_list = list(chil_bev1_1, chil_bev1_2)
chil_bev1n = lapply (hour_list, function (x) {x %>% complete(CLNDR_DT = seq.Date(min(CLNDR_DT), max(CLNDR_DT), by="day"), fill = list(QTY=0))})
```

## Notes:

The fill = list() function replaces the NAs with 0s.

CLNDR_DT is the name of the column that contains dates.